# Can the preposition "aus" be used to express ownership as "von" can?

Tags: preposition, genitive, possessive

In the dative case, *aus* is used to place emphasis on the object moving away from a location, whereas the preposition *von* is used to place emphasis on the place where the object is moving from, so naturally I am curious if the same works in Genitive.

Der Ring des Mannes:
Der Ring von des Mannes -- Man is the focus of the sentence,
Der Ring aus des Mannes -- Ring is the focus of the sentence.

Considering *aus* is of the same root as *out* I highly doubt it can be used in Possessive, but amn't for sure.

Comment: Both sentences are incorrect, with "aus" and with "von" (okay, you could do something like "Der Ring von des Mannes Finger..." or "Der Ring aus des Mannes Tasche...", but it's not really used). But maybe it helps if you complete your sentence example to better show what you try to put emphasis on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assumption is wrong. Whenever you have a certain preposition, you need a certain case. These are fixed pairs.

The only **exception** are the nine dual-way prepositions **an**, **auf**, **hinter**, **in**, **neben**, **über**, **unter**, **vor**, and **zwischen** which may go with either Dativ or Akkusativ, and mean a location vs. a direction.

Comment: Yes, I read something and realized I was confused, it was referring to swapping genitiv for dativ to express ownership.